# Does READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE mean storage outside the app sandbox or the SD card?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-permissions, mediastore

Not clear on whether requesting reads from image library in MediaStore means the storage internal to the device and outside the app sandbox OR the SD card. I imagine not every phone has an SD card. Just wanted to make sure I understand this permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allows an application to read from external storage. not only sandbox or SD Card it's read any external storage available on device. you can understand more from [document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).

Comment: More specifically if the phone has images only in internal storage (not the app's internal storage) could I access them? Or do they have to be on the SD card?

Comment: yes, you can access them from internal storage.